# Clickhouse query use regular expression

Tags: regex, database, clickhouse

I know clickhouse provides replaceRegexpOne() function, but I want to use a regular expression to query, not replace. Like MySQL:

```sql
select username 
from table 
where username  REGEXP '^[0-9]*$'.
```

Hope you can help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for `match()` I guess.

`match(haystack, pattern)`

> Checks whether the string matches the pattern regular expression. A re2 regular expression. The syntax of the re2 regular expressions is more limited than the syntax of the Perl regular expressions.

`WHERE match(column, 'pattern')`

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-search-functions/#matchhaystack-pattern

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve the problem. I tried to use "Match(column,'pattern')", but I got an error. Using "match(column,'pattern')" solved my problem, thanks again.